# Consolidating maxwells equation with relativity

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations

I know that maxwells equations are consistent with relativity. The following thought experiment seems to imply otherwise so I am wondering where my mistake lies.

Lets say we have some very large conductor loop(with a radius of many lightyears). At the center of the loop is some magnet which has a magnetic flux through the loop. Now to me it seems that maxwells equations imply that if I start to "turn off" this magnet, then while I am turning it off there will be an induced EMF along the loop. But how can be? Relativity would imply that the outside of the loop is not effected by what I do in the center for years.

Edit: when I say "maxwells equations imply" I am specifically refering to the equation that says that the EMF around a closed loop is equal to the rate of change of the magnetic flux through that loop.

Comment: Yes there will be a time delay. How does this mean there is inconsistency?

Comment: I thought that the change of flux through the surface would be instantaneous, in which case maxwells equation would imply no time delay.

Comment: Re *I thought that the change of flux through the surface would be instantaneous* What would make you think that?

Comment: I was picturing some source of a magnetic flux through the surface, located at the center of the loop. So i figured if this source were to be "turned off" it would instantaneouly no longer be creating this flux.

Comment: Yes once you turn the field off the flux is no longer being "created". It will still take time for anyone on the outside of the ring to know this has happened. If someone was near the center then the turning off would be near instantaneous compared to someone near the edge.

Answer (score 1):

The Maxwell-Faraday law says that the time derivative of the magnetic field us equal to rotation of the electric field *in the same position*. In a quasistatic case this law implies that a change of flux though a loop implies an EMF along it. Your example is not necessarily quasistatic. Only if the time scale of the time variation us much larger than the radius of the loop divided by the speed of light, it would qualify as quasistatic. Only in this case the well known flux rule applies.